# Python selenium invisible ram usage until it hits 99% by time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

EDIT: Fixed after implementing page refresh instead of opening new browsers.

I believe code isn't needed for this question and since it's way too long I'll try to explain the problem without it.

I made a selenium bot that checks a website for the freshly added content. It simply starts chromedriver, checks the nesecery page, quits the driver via driver.quit() and repeats forever in a loop but after about 24 hours ram usage hits above 95% and simply locks the computer. But in the task manager, there is nothing using the ram. Ram cleaning programs can't get rid of the invisible ram usage either.

Now what I am wondering is, is it because of my unlimited amount of browser turn on and offs even though I am closing the browser with driver.quit() or do I need to just change the code with page refreshing instead of turning the browser completely off and on all the time?

Just looking for ideas, not code. Thanks a lot.

Edit: The computer in the photo has 6 gb ram but it's at 93% when there is nothing using it. It becomes like that by time. When computer restarted ram usage is at normal levels like any idle computer. And the app on top is my bot.

[image: image here]

Comment: the answer is in your question just use refresh instead of `driver.quit()` using `driver.quit()` too much it will either crash your app or use massive resources

Comment: about not showing ram usage it does not necessarily show your app only because you are using binaries and packages based on a command-line based app